# Wordpress in subdirectory when root is not a wordpress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ubuntu, http-status-code-404

I am trying to install a wordpress site under domain.com/folder. The site itself work perfect, but when I go to a page (like: domain.com/folder/blog) it shows up:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /folder/blog/ was not found on this server.
```

I have tried to put this in my htaccess with no luck:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /folder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It still shows up as 404 error. It's probably worth mention that in the root domain folder, there's just a blank index page. No other wordpress installation. How can this be?

I am starting to think maybe it's a server configuration issue, though the mod_rewrite is loaded:
[image]

I am hosting a ubuntu 16.

Comment: Have you checked the `Permalinks Settings` in Wordpress and made sure that the url structure used is correct?

Comment: I found out that I forgot to set AllowOverride All in my apache conf file. So It was server related the error. I don't know if I should answer my own question in this case?

Comment: Glad to hear that it's resolved! Yeah you can ANSWER your own question. It will help others too who are facing similar issue! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Open "wp admin" of your sub domain, go to permalink settings and update the permalink settings.It will update the .htaccess file and all links on site works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Apache conf file right after the first line: (replace /var/www/html with the actual location of your root directory if it's different. This is just the default, if you're using 000-default.conf)

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```